# (Terminal) disable "Developer Settings" Android

Tags: android, terminal, developer-tools

My phone contains CyanogenMod ROM 13 (Android 6.0)
in the Developer Settings, I enabled this option:  **Simulate Secondary Display**

[image]

from "None" to **720, 1080p (dual screen)**

[image]

and my phone screen is too small so my screen went black but I can see the activity behind and can't tap on anything.
My phone is rooted and has TWRP Recovery with Terminal so, I was wondering if there's a Terminal command that can disable that option or the whole Developer Settings.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Safe Mode**

Boot into Safe Mode (details for what Safe Mode is and how to boot your device into Safe Mode can be found in the article How to Boot Android 4.1+ into Safe Mode:

**Method 1:**

hold down Power button until the power-menu pops up
press and hold the "restart" option
in the dialog box, select "Safe Mode" and hit "OK"

**Method 2:**

Reboot your device
hold the Vol+ and Vol- buttons at the same time to enter Safe Mode.
A "Safe Mode" watermark in the lower left corner tells you you've been successful. Obviously, you'd have to chose Method 2 as your device won't power up normally.

Now, while in Safe Mode, change the "Developer options" back to normal. Then do a normal reboot to leave Safe Mode.

**Hint:** If your device sticks in Safe Mode, power down and remove the battery for a few minutes. Then re-insert the battery, and the device should boot up normally.